# Serverside component for Next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am working on an open-source package meant to be used by a Next.js app. One of the components is a replacement for `Link`. In my package, the APIs are exposed using `exports` in `package.json`, like this:

```js
"exports": {
    "./link": "./lib/link/index.js",
    "./link-ssr": "./lib/link/ssr.js"
  }
```

Because it requires server-side rendering, I have two versions of the `Link` component, one for the client and the other one for SSR. The way I was able to get SSR to work was to use this special Webpack config (on the app that uses my package) in `next.config.js`:

```js
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    if (isServer) {
      config.resolve.alias['my-package/link'] = require.resolve(
        'my-package/link-ssr'
      );
    });
```

Because `link-ssr` is only used internally, I was trying to find a way to avoid exposing its API. One way I thought of using was to use a conditional `isServer` variable inside the client `link` component:

```js
const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'

if (isServer) {
  // Do server stuff
} else {
  // Do client stuff
}
```

The server component relies on `fs` (file server) and when I do this I get a Next.js compilation error when trying to access a page that uses the component:

```
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /
wait  - compiling...
error - ../lib/Links.js:5:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
  3 | exports.Links = void 0;
  4 | const path_1 = require("path");
> 5 | const fs_1 = require("fs");
  6 | /** Local rewrite cache to avoid non-required file system operations. */
  7 | let linksCache;
  8 | /**
```

Is this even feasible or are there other ways to avoid exposing `link-ssr` as a public component?

Comment: What's your build/compilation error?

Comment: I just edited the question and added the details of the error.

Comment: If the module depends on fs, then how are you able to use it in a browser? Sounds like maybe the module could be spilt up into separate modules. That or you could use dependency injection to supply the fs module.

Comment: Yes, `fs` is not supposed to be used in the browser which is why the `isServer` variable is there - I was hoping that Webpack could automatically split the client and server files automatically without having to use the `alias` config.

Comment: So the dependency injection approach would remove the `fs` import from your links module and instead you'd import the module in the calling module. The calling module would then pass in fs as a variable to a function. In the browser, you could either pass in a stub or `undefined`, in which case you wouldn't need the `isServer` check. You'd just skip the `fs` logic if `fs` is undefined. Does that make sense?

Comment: Alternatively you could import fs [dynamically](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports), in which case your module won't try to resolve that dependency until after you've verified your `isServer` check. However, a dynamic import would probably mean some restructuring as you'd need to wait for a promise to be resolved before using `fs`.

Comment: Now sure how this would work for a low-level component such as `Link` nor on the server side either? So far it looks like Webpack is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try with environment Variables. No need for additional dependencies.

For that, create an .env.production in your root-directory and put a Variable in there:

```
IS_SERVER=true
```

Then in your Sorcecode you can work with this ENV-Variable to check if you are at the Server or not:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  isServer = process.env.IS_SERVER;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is going to work? the check needs to happen on the package I am working on (it's included as a dependency of a Next.js app). Environment variables would be on the app itself?